# first click is of no effect when focusing on TextInput and then click elsewhere

Tags: react-native

[image]

as showed above, focus on the TextInput, then click elsewhere.

The first click on green area is of effect.

The first click on red area is of no effect ( it's a ListView ). The same thing happens on the first click of hardware back button on Android when previously focusing on TextInput.

Is it a bug or that I omit something ? ( the version of react-native I use is 0.16.0-rc )

Answer (score 2):

Add keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} on the ListView and it works